# How quora put that image on their home page?

Tags: html, css

I'm really a noob with HTML and CSS skills so I'd like to do this very simple question

I Saw on the [Quora Site](https://www.quora.com/) a very nice image (I'm not sure if that is a simply image or it's another attachment technic) and I'd like to build a similar in my page like the Quora did.

Someone can explain to me How to do it?

Comment: Open your browser. Press F12 to get dev tools. Click to inspect the element. Nose around the element and the CSS to see how it's done. That's the way to learn; by exploring and investigating.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Spudley but I have already did the element inspection and I didn't find any clue about that technic. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear which image you mean.

On the home page, there is a background image (stars), which gets inserted via CSS (`background` property), and an image (earth), which gets inserted via HTML (`img` element).

Comment: That was what I looked for... Background property! I didn't know that way of insert images. Thanks!

Comment: @kamusett: Here’s the specification: [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/colors.html#propdef-background-image), [CSS 3 (not yet a Recommendation)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/#the-background-image). Note that you should only include decorative images via CSS. For images important for the understanding/meaning of your document, you should keep using HTML.

Comment: Yes, I understood it. As the Quora did, in that case is just a decorative image, but anyway thanks for tips!